# How does std::thread generate concurrent processes on the OS?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdthread

I'm interested in implementing a thread class, purely as a learning exercise. What is the interface that `std::thread` uses to be able to run/stop concurrent processes on an OS? Is there a standard interface? Otherwise, what do I need to use for Windows 11?

Comment: Just pop open the thread header and you will see what it uses e.g. _beginthreadex then search on that.

Comment: *"Is there a standard interface?"* -- `std::thread` **is** the standard interface. To go a level below that, you need your OS-specific API.

Comment: @JaMiT I meant is there a standard interface std::thread uses to create threads on different operating systems.

Comment: @beangod *"I meant is there a standard interface std::thread uses to create threads on different operating systems."* -- Again, `std::thread` **is** the standard interface to create threads on different operating systems. The reason it exists is to standardize the different interfaces exposed by different operating systems.

Comment: @beangod it might be anything appropriate for compiler, `std::thread` may use platform APi or compiler's builtin function, the latter are undocumented or are part of compiler's documentation. It may not have implementation at all and be "implemented" as part of  compiler. Compiler is free to generate own code, or adjust generated code if it meets use of the standard component. `std::thread` IS the standard interface, using something else along with standard library leads into the area of "unspecified behaviour"

Comment: @beangod Reminder: One of the primary purposes of comments is to suggest improvements. The reason I brought up that `std::thread` is the standard interface is so that you can edit your question to focus on (and be tagged for) the Windows API for thread manipulation.

Comment: Note I see a lot of people use std::thread, but I've found std::async to be more useful abstractions. The returned future object can both be used to pass information back to the starting thread, but most of all the future is a RAII object and its destructor will synchronize with the stopping of the (underlying) thread.

Comment: Also know that starting (child) processes is not part of C++ or the standard library and always needs to be done with OS specific calls.

Comment: @PepijnKramer: "*its destructor will synchronize with the stopping of the (underlying) thread*" So will `std::jthread`.

Comment: In addition to the comments suggesting to to read the compiler headers, I'd suggest study of Boost. That C++ library is where the current standard C++ threading support started.

Comment: @NicolBolas That's true, but I am not in a C++20 (at work) world yet.

Comment: I honestly prefer using boost than the std counterparts. As they have more freedom, the implementations are faster and richer in features

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, `std::thread` is just a thin wrapper around the pthreads library, which in its turn is based on the C standard library (glibc). I actually do not use `std::thread` because it lacks a ton of features eg setting core affinity. I usually write my own thread class, which is simple enough.

Here is an interesting tutorial on getting started with pthreads:

https://riptutorial.com/pthreads

The reference should have been already installed on your system:

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html

Comment: *"The reference should have been already installed on your system:"* -- somehow I doubt that it is installed on the OP's system, given that the question mentions "for Windows 11".

Comment: @JaMiT Oopsie daisy :)

Comment: C++ is about abstraction, if the abstraction is good enough use it (portability). What you are doing is fine but it is optimization.